# Is Expo adequate for a middle or big size app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been using React Native for more than a year, but I never tried Expo deeply. I only made some test 3 months before. In that time I found that you were not allowed to write and integrate Java / Swift commponents if you needed to use them. 
Also I found a bit difficult to reload the app depending on the wifi signal. 
In some days, I will start a new middle size app. So I wonder if is it a good aproach to start it using Expo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is mostly opinion based and it is likely to be closed. It would be best to ask if or how you can solve an enterprise issue with Expo.

To me, while Expo is promising and interesting, is only good for either small apps or prototypes.

Pretty much you answered the question yourself. Native intengration is not possiblr and sooner or later you are going to need it in your app, otherwise you will be very limited.

Also, it adds another layer of dependency into your project. Let's say Expo updates something that breaks your app, you might need to re write everything.

Big companies or big projects cannot be stopped by this. So, to me, Expo is not a very good approach for mid size apps and above, but of course, it depends on your objective.

Maybe this big app of yours is a one time app, that needs no native integration whatsover and that you don't mind if you need to re write in the future, then yes, you could use Expo since it could help you speed up delivery.